# Flutter/just_audio: How can I identify the deviceType that is being used to play audio in?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, just-audio, background-audio

I am using `just_audio` with `audio_service` and `just_audio_background` to play audio in my app (in-app as well as background audio).

Is it possible for me to identify the type of device that is being used to play the audio? Such as, is the audio being played via the device (iOS/Android phone/tablet) itself, or perhaps via Bluetooth, CarPlay, AndroidAuto etc.

---

I could not find anything relevant in SO, in just_audio docs and issues. *And ChatGPT is hallucinating (it's telling me some methods that don't exist, but if they did - would have been exactly what I wanted)* :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages that should allow you to achieve what you want:

- `advanced_audio_manager` https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_audio_manager
- `audio_session` from the author of `just_audio` https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session This one doesn't provide you current device, but allows to react to changes like unplugging headphones, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_audio_manager looks perfect for my use-case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Platform` class that comes with Flutter.

```
 if(Platform.isAndroid){
   //Write Android code here
 }else if(Platform.isIOS){
  //Write ios code here
 }
```

Check out the `Platform` class you have access to other device types as well. I hope this solves your issues :)

Comment: That gives me the platform the app is running on. I am interested in the device (or at least device type) the audio is being played in. It can be running on an iPhone but the audio may be playing via Bluetooth, or in CarPlay?

Comment: oh for that just use the device_info package https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

Comment: I am using device_info_plus already. Do you know which specific field would have this (audio channel being used)?

Comment: I asked in device_info_plus also: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2168

Comment: No, `device_info_plus` won't help to get this information. Replying as core maintainer of Plus plugins.